# Flutter Firebase Notification with image

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How I can send Firebase notification with image from postman?
Now I am sending below request:

```
{   
    "to":"/topics/alltest",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Lorem Ipsum 3",
        "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
    },
    "data": {
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        "link": "/newsDetailPage?id=26"
    },
    "android":{
      "priority":"normal",
      "notification":{
         "image":"https://pngfre.com/wp-content/uploads/apple-png-image.jpg"
       }
    },
    "apns":{
      "headers":{
        "apns-priority":"5"
      },
      "payload":{
         "aps":{
           "mutable-content":1
         }
       },
       "fcm_options": {
           "image":"https://pngfre.com/wp-content/uploads/apple-png-image.jpg"
       }
    }
}
```

But the image is not showing in the notification.
When I try send notification from firebase console with image it works fine